# ExtsJs4 switch panels

Tags: extjs, extjs4, panel

In [ExtJs4 Layout Examples](http://dev.sencha.com/deploy/ext-4.0.0/examples/layout-browser/layout-browser.html) how do they switch right panel content when user clicks on menu items? Are there any examples with code samples?
I want exactly the same feature.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They create content panel with layout 'cards', add all examples as individual panels in to it, and then make them visible when you click through them. Check the source code - it's pretty obvious.